# Variables not differentiating

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm trying to do this little R,P,S simulator where for each player is designated a certain option, in this case: Rock, Paper or Scissors. In my first build, I had to manually write the play. In my second, the values were randomly chosen, keeping the "fun" in the game. Then I wanted those values to be printed before the result, but now all results are ties.
I kind of imagine that is happening because the player 1 and player 2 technically have the same value, but how can I fix this?

```
import sys
import random

options=["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
player1 = print(random.choice(options))
player2 = print(random.choice(options))

def compare (p1,p2):
    if p1==p2:
        print("Tie!")
    elif p1=="Rock":
        if p2=="Scissors":
            return ("Rock wins!")
        else:
            return ("Paper wins!")
    elif p1=="Scissors":
        if p2=="Rock":
            return ("Rock wins!")
        else:
            return ("Scissors wins!")
    elif p1=="Paper":
        if p2=="Scissors":
            return ("Scissors wins!")
        else:
            return ("Paper wins!")
    else:
        return ("Invalid imput!")
    sys.exit()

print(compare (player1, player2))
```

Comment: `print()` doesn't return anything, but that's what you're assigning to `player1` and `player2`.

Comment: help tip: check what are the values for `player1` and `player2` using `print(player1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question has been answered but I would still suggest a little optimization to the function:

Instead of:

```
def compare (p1,p2):
    if p1==p2:
        print("Tie!")
```

Use this:

```
def compare (p1,p2):
    if p1==p2:
        return("Tie!")
```

Makes the code a bit more self-contained and optimizes the execution.

Answer (score 1):

`print` returns `None`, so by doing

> ```
> player1 = print(random.choice(options))
> player2 = print(random.choice(options))
> ```

both `player1` and `player2` are `None`, and therefore

> ```
> if p1==p2:
>     print("Tie!")
> ```

will always be executed.

Instead, use

```
player1 = random.choice(options)
player2 = random.choice(options)
```